# Forms with responsive layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Why does the textfield doesn't follow the `.span1` rule? What can I do to fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/aurorius/aNRBn/

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
          <fieldset>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Focused input</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input class="focused span1" id="focusedInput" type="text"
                value="This is focused" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Uneditable input</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <span class="span1 uneditable-input">Some value here</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
​
```

A quick way to fix it is by changing `row-fluid` to `row`. But how do I fix it while still using the `row-fluid` tag?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try using an input instead of a span?

```
<input class="uneditable-input span1" value="Some value here" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uWbe9/

Comment: With input, I can now type new values into the field and setting it to `readonly="readonly"` would only make it looks disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a CSS precedence issue - your width:100%; is getting over-written by other styles. To fix, add another class to it to re-take top precedence, i.e.:

```
.container-fluid .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
width: 100%;
[.. rest of styles here]
}​
```

Adding the ".container-fluid " in front gives it precedence again.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lukem/HA26E/1/

CSS precedence rules:http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/